# my reactjs button design feels slow onTouch on tablet vs tablet buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I built a web app that is viewed on tablets. It was made with reactjs and a express backend. It's a relatively small app that simple in that it just display items and allows users to customizer order items and such.

This was my attempt to create a custom 'check box' style button.

I have an array of items `var items =  ['ab','bc','cd','de','ef','fg','gh','hi','ij']` that can at times have about 30 elements total.

I create another array to list my items by pushing each elements in as li blocks

```
var itemsList = ;
items.forEach(item => {
  toppingsList.push (
      <li className={(this.checkChosen(item) === item) ? 'itemChosen' : 'itemNotChosen'} onClick={(e)=>{this.handleItemClicked(item)}}><p>{item}</p></li>
    )
})
```

From here I create those `<li></li>` where `checkChosen(item)` checks if the topping is inside the 'selected pile'. The `handleItemClicked(item)` pushed an item into this components state.

```
this.state = {
   itemsChosen = [];
}
```

It also checks to see if it's within the itemsChosen state and either adds or removes it.

I run this on a Lenovo tab 10 on a local host and it seems like these buttons have a delay, as if the onClick isn't very responsive. I used a similar method for a pin pad design.

I thought this could be an issue with the tablet but when I invoke the native keyboard for the pin pad (just an input type = "number" ) it feels quick, and smooth how you would expect the web app to run.

This method doesn't seem to be very demanding, but is it?

Comment: Yes. Why are you creating a separate list, and pushing actual li elements to it? Use `.filter()` and `.map()` to find the elements you want, and display them out, thus not allocating a separate array each time.

Comment: I dont think this should be comparably slow compared to filter, or map, as the list is not super big. Have you tried to separate only this code to a small react app and test if its slow there? It could be the rest of the logic.